# Need to add Contribution page for "in kind" donations with image upload

Tags: civicontribute, custom-fields

I am using CiviCRM 4.7 in Wordpress.
I have taken on a new project for a local charity, what they want is to have a donation page set up for furniture, clothing ect. They have plans of doing several other things as well and CiviCRM is a perfect fit, except I cannot for the life of me figure out how to create a custom contribution page with an image upload field. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Custom Fields to a set of fields that are specifically used for Contributions. One such field could be a file field type - and therefore you should then be able to include that in to a Profile that you then include on the Contribution form. I can flesh this out more, but if you know your way around creating Custom Fields and Profiles the above might be enough to help you advance.

Comment: Thanks for accepting - could you give it a nudge with a +1 since that is what SE expects (unless you don't have the rights to do so yet)

Comment: That did the trick. Still having some issues with the form, but the file upload as a custom field added to the profile worked. Thanks for your response.